# MS SQL Server 2008 - UPDATE a large database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to `UPDATE` just one data in a large `TABLE`
What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
  SELECT * from TABLE WHERE status='N'
  UPDATE TABLE set status='Y' where status='N'
```

Comment: Does this table have a primary key? Like unique id, if u need to update only one record.

Comment: Yes it does have.

Comment: If the table is really big, it's usually a good idea to do the update in batches instead of all in one big update.

Comment: then use that the id of that record to update that record. Eg: `UPDATE TABLE set status='Y' where tableId=99` it will update that one data only.

Comment: What is *large* in your context? In any case you don't need to run a `SELECT` before you run your `UPDATE`.

Comment: What is `one data`? One row? One column?

Comment: One column. Sorry for not being specific enough. The status column.

Answer (score 2):

I assume table is very very large.
Then may be you should create temp/permanent Filtered index on table

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Temp_Table_Status
ON dbname.dbo.Table(Status)
WHERE Status='N'
GO
```

else your query is correct.

```
UPDATE TABLE set status='Y' where status='N'
```

Answer (score 0):

"Most efficient" is much like "most beautiful". It has no absolute meaning. How do you measure "efficient". IMO, by far the most efficient mechanism is to use a single update query. Your query should actually be written to avoid pointless updates:

```
update table set col = 'Y' where col <> 'Y';
```

The where clause will make it "most efficient".  And note that you might need to account for null values in the where clause - know your data. Some might argue for batching the updates in order to save space. If you do this on a regular basis, then you should have generally have sufficient space in the database and log to do this without attempting to pointlessly manage bits of diskspace.