# SQL Server: Filtered Indexes versus Indexed Views

Tags: sql-server, indexing

What are the relative merits of each? Both seem to limit the number of rows and columns through which your query needs to trawl, so what determines the basis for choosing one over the other?

Comment: *Filtered Index* requires a pretty simple *condition* to be possible, while an *Indexed View* has a rather extensive, long list of preconditions that have to be met. An Indexed View also isn't about reducing the number of rows - it's about speeding up (most `SELECT`) queries against that view be persisting and indexing the data that the view shows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indexed view

- can include columns based on an expression.
- can include joins of multiple tables.
- can be referenced directly in user SQL statements.
- allows all deterministic expressions
- has complicated prerequisites, but is simple and consistent to use (select * from [indexedview])

A [filtered index](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/)

- is limited to the columns contained within the table.
- only allows simple expressions for the filter.
- is simple to implement, but the optimizer will determine if usage is appropriate when the base table is queried.

Neither of them can use non-deterministic expressions.

Comment: +1 Also, (non-indexed) views and table-valued functions can be built on top of indexed views (consider `WITH(NOEXPAND)` hint).

Answer (score 1):

Index View :

i) I have to get result from more than one table.

ii) I create Index on this view to boost performance.

Filtered Index :

i) There are lot of record in single table.

ii) A particular where condition with specific value contain lot of records. and this condition will be very frequently use.Or this condition will be use in very important query where performance is of utmost importance.
In this case we may create filtered index on table.

Check my answer for example

[MS SQL Server 2008 - UPDATE a large database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675715/ms-sql-server-2008-update-a-large-database/43675902#43675902)